# Exporting only meshes contained in Object3Ds to GLTF in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I've had a good hunt but can't find the solution:

the GLTFExport for Three.js allows for specific objects to be exported when they're named in the exporter.

My situation:

I have a random number of Object3Ds with child Meshes in my scene that I'd like to export, however I have removed everything from my scene apart from the objects and their child meshes and a helper to show face normals direction, and I still get the error:

`Uncaught Error: THREE.GLTFExporter: userData can't be serialized`

Previously I didn't have the Object3Ds and just had the meshes by themselves as children of the scene and the export worked fine. Unfortunately having the meshes within the Objects is needed for the program to work and the documentation suggests that they can be exported.

**Can anyone think of a way around this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userData is a field on every Object3D that is normally set to {}. It's intended to allow the user (you) to store data of your own on an Object3D or derived class, without messing up the internals of the object.. You may have some .userData set on an object3D in your scene..

The easy way to find out is to `scene.traverse((o)=>{console.log(o.userData)})` and see if there is userData stored on any of your objects.

You can make a copy of your scene before you export using var sceneCopy = scene.clone(true);

then `sceneCopy.traverse((o)=>{o.userData={};});`

and then try to export sceneCopy.

Give that a try and if it doesn't work, try back here :)

hth

Comment: THANKS! I do have userData.... I knew I'd seen that term somewhere before!

I'll try that solution you suggest and let you know!

Comment: I had some issues with your code ... I could print to console and see the objects with userData but when i tried on the duplicate scene it unfortunately threw an error :( three.min.js:498 `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  I was able to remove the userData from the original objects but this will then screw up any further interaction with the meshes in the scene....

Comment: That call stack size exceeded is a clue as to the problem. It sounds like some utility or client code has put some data in the userData that contains a circular reference, or is otherwise unserializable. Can you report back with what the userData contains on the objects you found them on?

Comment: Yep. I've got a bunch of meshes in my scene that I need to find the parents to when they're clicked. I've added the `userData.parent = parentObject` so i can get the parent object by simply typing `arrayObject.parent` (this has been called from a variable specifying the first object found in the raycaster).... I've found that the call stack size issue comes down to the `.clone` command. I tested it by creating a new exporter scene, finding each object3D in an array and then cloning the Object3D. As soon as clone command is hit, I get the error.....by the way, i have no idea about serialize

Comment: Aaaaaand.....like a moron I've just realised that I don't actually need that .parent as a userData addition.... it's already in there =_=, I've taken it out now, I'll do some more testing and see if that fixes it.

Comment: OMG that actually worked! Talk about no bloody clue! Thanks so much for your help getting to the bottom of this issue Manthrax, I was totally stuck before your suggestions.

Comment: w00t! Glad I could help! Upvote my answer.. ahh u accepted.. good enough :P :D

Yeah there is a method on most THREE objects, called .toJSON that allows you to serialize objects to JSON.. but when it hits a circular reference, it blows up.

You can then take that resulting JSON blob and save it or reload it into a scene using the THREE.ObjectLoader().parse( or .load(

I'm guessing that the GLTF exporter is using a similar mechanism and that's why it died. userData is mostly supposed to contain bare javascript objects, and not reference to other data that cant be converted to json.